# Unable to Reset Verified ReCapcha

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I am using ReCaptcha 2 on a webpage. The user enters the username and password and is validated through an Ajax call. (Of course, the user will need to verify ReCaptcha before clicking the submit button). If the validation fails, I want to give another chance to resubmit data. However, the ReCaptcha validation fails with 'duplcate submission error'  It seems that a validated ReCaptcha cannot be submitted again. So my question is -- how can I reset a verified  ReCaptcha so that the user could reverify it? I am using JavaScript, jQuery and Vue.js

Answer (score 0):

Use the reset() method, e.g

```
grecaptcha.reset();
```